# Visual Studio 2017 tries to connect to Local Mysql with an IP when debugging

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

For some reason After a windows 10 upgrade resulting to a bsod event, I had to do a fresh install of my PC. I have visual studio 2017 and MySQL set up for my C# ASP.NET EF projects.  I have installed MySQL similar to my old system  and I have a laptop with similar setup which works okay.

The problem is when I try to debug the application tries to connect to the local mysql(version 5.7.23) using an IP instead of localhost and  fails to authenticate.

```
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException HResult= 0x80004005 
 Message=Authentication to host '' for user '' using method 
`'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'xxx.xxx.x.x' 
(using password: NO) Source=MySql.Data'`
```

When I run  update-database etc in the console of visual studio it connects to database alright and update tables etc.  But it fails to connect when I debug the application.

I have maintained using  localhost as string and changed to the IP still cannot connect on debug.

Answer (score 0):

On the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Data Sources (or choose the Shift+Alt+D keys).

In the Choose Data Source window select MySql Database and press Continue.

in the Add Connection window, set server name: 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Then test again using the debug to ensure it's now fixed.

Comment: Thanks I tried but I got the same problem.  However what fixed the problem was adding   <remove name="RoleManager" /> in the modules section of webconfig